# Small typo with 'History Stack Exchange is almost there!‏' email

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, email

I just received this email overnight, and there is a very small typo:

> The proposal you've committed To is almost ready to go to beta! We
>   just need a few more people to commit to using the site.

*To* needs to be changed to *to*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed now. Thanks for the report.